# The editor process exited with an error: spawn webstorm ENOENT

Tags: npm, intellij-idea, webstorm

I am trying to tell my terminal how to open WebStorm, but importantly actually, to tell my dev environment where it is located so I can click on the errors output in the web browser and directly take me to the correct file:line where the error is occurring.

[image]

I can open WebStorm with `webstorm` down to my alias, just pointing to the path does not work:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME:/home/hutber/WebStorm/bin
alias webstorm=/home/hutber/WebStorm/bin/webstorm.sh
```

Even though I can type and open WebStorm with `webstorm` still I get the following errors in my CLI:

```
Could not open [...param].jsx in the editor.
The editor process exited with an error: spawn webstorm ENOENT.

To set up the editor integration, add something like REACT_EDITOR=atom to the .env.local file in your project folder and restart the development server.
```

Comment: looks like `webstorm` is not in your `$PATH`; try creating a symlink in `/usr/local/bin` as instructed in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2023.2/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html#1db03c5a- does it help?

Comment: Brilliant, indeed: `sudo ln -s /home/hutber/WebStorm/bin/webstorm.sh /usr/local/bin/webstorm` was the solution. I had mapped things in my .bashrc, but this didn't work!!